# Converting commented PDF with Ghostscript but without the comments

Tags: pdf, comments, ghostscript

Gentlepeople,

I'm using the command line version of GhostScript for Windows to convert PDF to PNG images. However I noticed that also the annotations (such as comments, shapes, attached files - anything the user can put on top of the original PDF) were converted and appear in the image output. Is there any way to let Ghostscript ignore comments in PDF?

Your help is appreciated :-)

Comment: Hmm, I found [this software](http://www.verypdf.com/wordpress/201111/how-to-remove-pdf-comments-to-reduce-pdf-size-11929.html) which looks like it will do it. I expect this is commercial Windows software, and I am not sure it can do this programmatically. But at least it indicates that it can (probably!) be done.

Comment: Do you have a sample PDF showing these 'annotations'? (I might know of another CLI tool that can remove these, but I'd like to test this before I recommend it...)

Comment: @pipitas I've put a sample annotated PDF to http://dl.dropbox.com/u/78806333/Annotated.pdf    ... The black numbers are the original PDF, everything else is Drawing/Comments/Attachments on top. I assume this stuff is put in its own layer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same question.  I found a setting in GhostScript which turns off comment printing (called annotations in their documentation).  http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm

the switch is `-dShowAnnots=false` which is case sensitive. For example, to convert a file to PNG (which was also what I wanted to do), you would use something like:

```
gswin64c -sDEVICE=png16m -sOutputFile="OutFile.png" -r300 -dShowAnnots=false "InputFile.pdf"
```

Using this command line format gave me exactly what I wanted: The first page of the source PDF converted to true-color PNG format without transparency, at 300 DPI, without any of the comments from the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Had this error:

> BBox has zero width or height, which is not allowed.

Found this hint, but without solution: https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=696889

I already used

`-dPreserveAnnots=false`

but the error came nonetheless.

`-dShowAnnots=false` fixes it for me.